# Roundcube keeps loading when trying to make a new filter with managesieve

Tags: dovecot, roundcube, sieve

I'm trying to install an autoresponder for Roundcube with Managesieve and probably doing something wrong. 
Roundcube is working fine, /var/log/roundcube/errors is empty.
But, when I try to make a new filter in the 'settings' area of Roundcube, where managesieve displays the button 'filters', and I try to make a new filter for the autoresponder, it keeps loading.
What could be wrong? Perhaps I'm looking at the wrong logs?

The mail.log with dovecot debug 'on' gives:

```
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve-login: Login: user=<info@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=95.85.2.99, lip=95.85.2.99, mpid=10827, secured, session=<CVYYrJ9SXK9fVQJj>
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=dirsize:storage=0
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Effective uid=150, gid=8, home=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, alt=
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904) initializing
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: include: sieve_global is not set; it is currently not possible to include `:global' scripts.
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using active Sieve script path: /var/customers/mail/sieve/mydomain.com/info/.dovecot.sieve
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using script storage path: /var/customers/mail/sieve/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Using permissions from /var/customers/mail/sieve/mydomain.com/info: mode=0700 gid=-1
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: Relative path to sieve storage in active link:
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file storage: sync: Synchronization active
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Debug: sieve: file script: Opened script `roundcube' from `/var/customers/mail/sieve/mydomain.com/info/roundcube.sieve'
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<info@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=10829, secured, session=<gv4ZrJ9SzKF/AAAB>
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=dirsize:storage=0
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Effective uid=150, gid=8, home=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, alt=
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: imap(info@mydomain.com): Logged out in=44 out=513
Jun 23 14:23:44 host dovecot: managesieve(info@mydomain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=67/557
Jun 23 14:24:41 host postfix/smtpd[10834]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 14:24:41 host postfix/smtpd[10834]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jun 23 14:24:42 host dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: Disconnected, session=<ckKMr59Spux/AAAB>
Jun 23 14:26:02 host postfix/anvil[10756]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:80.82.77.203) at Jun 23 14:21:17
Jun 23 14:26:02 host postfix/anvil[10756]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:80.82.77.203) at Jun 23 14:21:17
Jun 23 14:26:02 host postfix/anvil[10756]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jun 23 14:21:17
Jun 23 14:26:42 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 14:26:42 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
Jun 23 14:26:42 host dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS handshaking: Disconnected, session=<Pq21tp9SuOx/AAAB>
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3-login: Login: user=<info@mydomain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=81.206.125.28, lip=95.85.2.99, mpid=10851, TLS, session=<yKIrt59SovZRzn0c>
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: mail=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Added userdb setting: plugin/quota=dirsize:storage=0
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Effective uid=150, gid=8, home=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Debug: Namespace inbox: type=private, prefix=, sep=, inbox=yes, hidden=no, list=yes, subscriptions=yes location=maildir:/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info
Jun 23 14:26:49 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Debug: maildir++: root=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, index=, indexpvt=, control=, inbox=/var/vmail/mydomain.com/info, alt=
Jun 23 14:26:50 host dovecot: pop3(info@mydomain.com): Disconnected: Logged out top=0/0, retr=0/0, del=0/4, size=64401
Jun 23 14:27:35 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: connect from unknown[80.82.77.203]
Jun 23 14:27:37 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: warning: unknown[80.82.77.203]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jun 23 14:27:37 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: disconnect from unknown[80.82.77.203] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Jun 23 14:28:42 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Jun 23 14:28:42 host postfix/smtpd[10846]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 quit=1 commands=2
```

Log mail.err is empty

dovecot -n gives:

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-79-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
first_valid_uid = 150
last_valid_uid = 150
mail_gid = mail
mail_location = maildir:/var/vmail/%d/%n
mail_uid = vmail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = /var/customers/mail/sieve/%d/%n/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = /var/customers/mail/sieve/%d/%n
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@mydomain.com
protocols = " imap sieve pop3 sieve"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0666
    user = vmail
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  process_min_avail = 1
  service_count = 1
  vsz_limit = 64 M
}
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_cipher_list = ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
ssl_protocols = !SSLv2 !SSLv3
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = " quota sieve"
}
protocol sieve {
  mail_plugins =
}
```

Comment: Can you see your existing filters in Roundcube? If not, the first port of call is to examine whether Roundcube even tries to connect to Sieve, and if so, if that connection is being rejected. Every time I've seen an issue with Roundcube indefinitely loading, with sieve and other plugins, it's always been due to one of those two reasons.

Comment: Hi, I can see in settings>filters 1 filterset named 'Roundcube'. If I try to add a new filterset or if I try to add a filter within this existing filterset 'Roundcube', indefinitely loading occurs. How could I see whether the connection is being rejected or if Roundcube even attemps to connect?

Comment: So, first off, edit your dovecot.conf and set (either add it or change it the debug level : `mail_debug = yes` and then restart Dovecot. Then, run `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` and try and add a new sieve filter. It will output A LOT. Copy the output, add it to your question (redact any values you feel are private). Once done, turn OFF debugging in dovecot.conf and restart dovecot.

Comment: Thanks, this Dovecot debug setting gives some more info, I just added it to the question. It seems something isn't set? "sieve_global is not set"

Comment: Could you hop into a chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60968/856155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking directory permissions on the users sieve location are set correctly (`chmod -R 0700 /var/path/to/sieve`) it became apparent that the issue was within Roundcube itself, ultimately it seems upgrading from 1.2-beta to 1.2.5 stable fixed the problem.